# What exactly is runtimeOnly on androidx.appcompat:appcompat

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I'm working with old version of appcompat, but error after migrate to androidX.
*implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'*
Should i use `implementation` instead of `runtimeOnly` ?

Answer (score 1):

After androidx migration your dependency would have been changed to following:

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1"
```

If above is already present in your build.gradle then you can safe remove appcompat-v7 dependency.

As far as using `implementation` or `runtimeOnly` it totally depends upon dependency usage. If its usage in compile time then use `implementation` or if this just require in runtime use `runtimeOnly`.

Answer (score 0):

To get your answer please refer to the link: [Dependency configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations)

According to the description mentioned in above link:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Better use `implementation` or `runtimeOnly` ?